Argument and Winding Number
currently I have the following easy question regarding the winding around a point and the argument function of the logarith.
Revision:
Consider the following setup:

Some simply connected domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb C$ where for simplicity we might take $\Omega = \mathbb C$.
Some closed, piecewise $C^1$-curve $\gamma \colon [0,t] \to \mathbb \Omega$ that might or not surround the point $z$. For simplicity assume that the curve $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve. It is important here that the curve is not explicitly given and thus one cannot use the usual techniques.
Now consider the principle branch of the logarithm by taking the branch cut from $(-\infty,0]$ such that $\arg \colon \mathbb C - (-\infty,0] \to [-\pi,\pi)$.
Consider some point $z \in \mathbb C - (-\infty,0]$ or basically any arbitary point in the complex plane off the branch.

Question: Looking at $\arg(z-\gamma(t))$ or a similiar quantity for the argument can one determine whether or not curve $\gamma$ winds around the point $z$ such that after forming a loop the point $z$ is contained in the connected component of $\mathbb C - \gamma$?
Simple Case: Take $z=2$ and $\gamma(t) = 2+
2\exp(2\pi i t)$ where $t \in [0,1]$ then for $\arg(-\gamma(t))$ there exist two distinct points in time where the argument is $0$. But this doesn't maybe seem sufficient since if we start with a point $z$ that is outside the loop then shifting the function by $z$ and applying $-\gamma(t)$ seems to behave similiary but clearly choosing some other curve it does not wind around $0$.
Thanks in advance!

How do you define the interior of the loop?

One could define it as the bounded connected component as $\mathbb C \setminus \gamma$.

What if there are several of them?

I would be only interested in the case where one only forms one loop for my problem. Otherwise if there are say finitly many then I guess one would define the interior of union of all the bounded connected components of $\mathbb C \setminus \gamma$.

I think this needs a revise.  There is a typo in the domain definition for $\gamma$ and the domain for $\text{arg}$ is not stated.  $\gamma(t)$ also has a typo and winding number shows up in the title but not the body of the question.  To the extent you are interested in winding numbers then I'd suggest considering the set of null homotopic loops on the unit circle.

How do you define the function $\arg$? Principal value?

The "interior" of a loop is not well-defined without an extra hypothesis, such as that the loop forms a simple closed curve. Imagine a figure 8 curve: what's the inside and what's the outside?

I believe I made the correct changes, basically I am interested whether or not a simple closed curve winds around a given point $z$. For the case of a simple closed curve / loop sufficies where the interior of what it encloses can be defined as the bounded component of $\mathbb C - \gamma$. The argument function would come from the logarithm after taking an appropriate branch but here one can start with the standard example.

you still have $\gamma \colon [0,t] \to \mathbb \Omega$ and then say $\gamma(t) = 2+
\exp(2\pi t)$ so $\gamma$ is a single point;  I suggest changing the domain of $\gamma$ to $[0,1]$.  If you want $\gamma$ to be a simple closed curve then a point $p$ is in the bounded component of $\mathbb C-[\gamma]$ iff the winding number $n\big(\gamma, p\big)\in \big{1,-1\big}$; this is the Jordan Curve Theorem-- quoting Munkres Topology this result for the index "is surprisingly difficult; it is in fact a rather deep result".  Ahlfors has this as a guided exercise.

@user8675309 Sorry there is an obvious typo in the sense that $\gamma(t) = 2 + 2\exp(2\pi * i *t)$ in the sense that one forms a circle of radius $2$ around $2$.

@user8675309 I am also aware of the theorem that you quoted but my problem is given by the fact that the explicit calculation of $n(\gamma,p)$ is not possible since the curve $\gamma$ is explicit but I know that $\log(z-\gamma(t))$ crosses once the principle branch but this doens't seem sufficient to say that we form a closed simple curve around $z$.
